# Preserving summernote styles with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, summernote

I have a rails project that uses the basic CRUD forms. I have loaded in the summernote gem into a text area. Upon saving the form and outputting onto the "show" page, all styles are there. When I click "edit", it takes me back to the edit page, and all of the summernote styles are gone. Do you know what's causing this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/HackerWins/summernote/issues/59

This is a common issue. See above. Styles should be saving to the db as inline, you can then print them out.